# How to fix “vec as location” error in read_csv?

Tags: r, readr

When I use the read_csv function and the group_by function, I always get an error that says “vec as location”. None of my peers have gotten this issue, and I can’t find any solutions anywhere on the internet. Does anyone have any possible solutions?

I’ve tried restarting R, and I’m on the latest version. I can’t think of anything else to fix this because I don’t fully understand what this error message entails.

Answer (score 0):

If it runs on a different computer with R then its probably a corrupt package,
I would start a new r session install vctrs install.packages("vctrs") install readr install.packages("readr") try your code again